# Jersey 1.7 and angular js. prevent resending request

Tags: angularjs, nginx, glassfish, jersey

Good day,

We have REST service that is running very long. The problem is exactly after 10 minutes request to the resource is repeated for the same user. I dont know if it is in Angular side which uses NGINX as proxy, or it is in Glassfish 3.1 server where our service located. On browser I inspected, I cant see the second request. 
Does anybody have clue?

Comment: Without code, I don't know what is wrong. But I want to say, if a ajax request is running as long as 10 min, you might want to break it into several small requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set timeinterval

```
function bindBorrowings()
{
//code
}

var setTimeOut = setInterval(function () {
           $scope.$apply(bindBorrowings());
       }, 5000);
```

clear interval when you navigate to other page

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
           if (next.$$route.controller != "CurrentctrlName") {
               clearInterval(setTimeOut); // clear interval here
           }
       });
```